# Php printer Out of memory error

Tags: php, apache, pecl

I want to use printer extension PHP. So I downloaded the dll and installed it on my wamp server but now, when I want to open my printer, I'm faced with this problem:

Here is code:

```
$printer = "\\\\MARKETING1-PC\\Canon LBP2900"; 
if($ph = printer_open($printer)) 
{ 

   $content = 'test';


   // Set print mode to RAW and send PDF to printer 
   printer_set_option($ph, PRINTER_MODE, "RAW"); 
   printer_write($ph, $content); 
   printer_close($ph); 
} 
else "Couldn't connect...";
```

And the error is

```
 Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 1048576) (tried to allocate 4294967295 bytes) in C:\wamp\www\test\sell_report.php on line 10
```

Maybe the problem is the dll that I downloaded?

Comment: 4,294,967,295 bytes?  4GB is a lot of RAM!

Comment: Which line is line 10?

Comment: @MikeBrant exactly on if line

Comment: @SurrealDreams yep i think maybe problem is for dll

Answer (score 0):

I'd try a local printer first, without going over the network.

Also, the printer extension has been written for PHP4 and never had an official release. I doubt it's usable at all.

You're better of generating PDF or .ps files and using CLI commands to print them.

Comment: my friend at least i can connect to the printer, my problem was in the network,  when i try it locally its ok